# Why did facebook connect stop working for me? (like buttons)

Tags: html, facebook

I have configured my website so that it has the facebook like button on each blog post. I don't remember making any changes breaking this, but it's suddenly not working for me. The button just does not appear.

The full page is at http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4d80169e4aa5d8050d716c94 (it should appear right under "posted: ..")

The relevant code however is this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">
    </script >
</head>
```

...

```
<fb:like href="http://lastyearswishes.com/blog/view/4d80169e4aa5d8050d716c94" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" font="lucida grande"></fb:like>
```

I am not seeing any kind of error messages either.

Comment: It shows up fine in all browsers for me. Maybe your browser is blocking it?

Comment: @Luke that's very odd. I've tested it and a friend of mine has tested it. Doesn't show up in either place :/

Comment: its there on my comp =/ even clicked it. would you like a screenshot or something?

Comment: @Luke, no it appears on mine now. Literally just a few hours after posting this question. That is very odd.

Answer (score 2):

There's an active thread about this problem on the Facebook Platform Developer Forum. One poster suggested adding this line of code before the like button code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

This works for me, but other folks are still having problems with disappearing like buttons.

Comment: Thread on their bug tracker: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15879

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to check:

- Are you currently logged into the browser that you are accessing (this shouldn't make or break it though)?
- Javascript turned on (check your developer toolbar if using Firefox)?
- Cookies turned on?
- Not blocking cookies for a anything facebook related

Try another browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari and dare I say, IE).

Oh, works fine for me too!